# To @ or not to @ in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Why do you have to refer to your class properties sometimes with @ and sometimes without it? If I were to remove the '@completed' and replace with 'completed', the test fails. But in the Project class the tasks property is set the same way but can be used without the @.

```
class Task
  attr_accessor :size, :completed

  def initialize(options = {})
    @completed = options[:completed]
    @size = options[:size]
  end

  def completed?
    @completed
  end

  def mark_completed
    @completed = true
  end
end


class Project
  attr_accessor :tasks

  def initialize
    @tasks = []
  end

  def done?
    tasks.reject(&:completed?).empty?
  end

  def total_size
    tasks.sum(&:size)
  end

  def remaining_size
    tasks.reject(&:completed?).sum(&:size)
  end
end


describe "estimates" do
    let (:project) { Project.new }
    let (:done) { Task.new(size: 2, completed: true) }
    let(:small_not_done) { Task.new(size: 1) }
    let(:large_none_done) { Task.new(size: 4) }

    before(:example) do
      project.tasks = [done, small_not_done, large_none_done]
    end

    it "can calculate total size" do
      expect(project.total_size).to eq(7)
    end

    it "can calculate remaining size" do
      expect(project.remaining_size).to eq(5)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is off-topic, but I would have implemented `done?` as `tasks.all?(&:completed?)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr_accessor :tasks` is equivalent to:

```
def tasks
  @tasks
end

def tasks=(val)
  @tasks = val
end
```

When you call `tasks`, you are calling the `tasks` method, which just returns the value of the `@tasks` variable. The accessor method will always be used from *outside* of the class (since the instance variable isn't visible), but you can use either from within the class, since they're functionally equivalent *for this implementation of the tasks method*. However, you may want to use the `tasks` accessor if you may ever do something other than just returning `@tasks` - by hiding the variable access behind a method, you are free in the future to do more complex work in that accessor, without having to change the places that you use it.